# Chrome Extension - Ace Editor worker fails to load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, web-worker, ace-editor

I'm trying to embed the [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/) into a browser extension, using JS mode with the error-detecting worker.

In **Firefox** it works with no issues. In **Chrome**, the editor runs but it fails to load the worker which parses and reports errors in the JS. The reason it fails is due to a Content Security Policy error in the worker loader, which uses `importScripts`:

```
importScripts('chrome-extension://<extuuid>/js/worker-javascript.js');
```

```
Refused to load the script 'chrome-extension://<extuuid>/js/worker-javascript.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src ..."
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I'd think the CSP directive for `importScripts` in workers would be `worker-src` but the console error consistently says it fails the `script-src` test (specifically `script-src-elem`), and disregards my settings for `worker-src`.
I've tried adjusting my CSP `script-src` to the following; none work (p.s. yes, some aren't even valid – I'm desperate):

```
script-src 'self' blob:;
script-src 'self' blob: chrome-extension:;
script-src 'self' blob: *;
script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: blob: *;
script-src 'self' blob: chrome-extension://*/js/worker-javascript.js;
script-src 'self' blob: *://*/js/worker-javascript.js;
```

The only CSP that actually worked so far was copy-pasting the entire chrome extension url...

```
script-src 'self' blob: chrome-extension://<extuuid>/js/worker-javascript.js;
```

...which can't possibly be the right way of doing this, especially if the `extuuid` is liable to change.

**So, the question is, how do I permit extension urls in the CSP for `importScripts`?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

---

**EDIT:**

I'm just loading ace.js in the extension options page `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
    <title>Custom WebScripts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/options.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ace.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/options.js"></script>
</head>
```

Specifically, the `ace.js` file includes a copy of the `ace.js` source, followed by `mode-javascript.js` and `theme-monokai.js` inline in the script.

Comment: It depends on where you import it. To run a worker or import a script into a standard extension page such the popup you don't need any modifications to CSP: just use a relative path like `/js/worker-javascript.js`, simple as that.

Comment: That'd be great! Any thoughts on how to force Ace to load from a relative path, short of modifying the Ace source code itself?

Comment: My point is there should be no need to modify anything, it just works. So maybe there's   a bug in Chrome or in Ace.

Comment: Hmm, so I tried your suggestion anyway and modified the Ace source to load '/js/worker-javascript.js' and 'js/worker-javascript.js' and still neither work: `The URL '/js/worker-javascript.js' is invalid.` Again, Ace works fine in FF. It wouldn't surprise me if there *is* a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Show us where you load it.

Answer (score 1):

> In **Firefox** it works with no issues. In **Chrome**, the editor runs but it fails ...

"No issues" maybe because of 2 reasons:

- because of [bug](https://csplite.com/csp/test367/#bug_Firefox_worker_console_violation) in Firefox - it does not show CSP errors in workers in the console, but send violation reports with these errors.
- because Firefox does not apply CSP of parent document inside worker, but Chrome - does. Firefox requires own CSP header be sent along with worker script.

> I'd think the CSP directive for `importScripts` in workers would be `worker-src`

In the modern browsers `importScripts()` is covered by a `script-src`. In older browsers it was covered by a `child-src`. The `worker-src` covers only `new Worker()` / `new SharedWorker()` / `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` APIs.

> Specifically, the `ace.js` file includes a copy of the `ace.js` source, followed by `mode-javascript.js` and `theme-monokai.js` inline in the script.

Ace is a cloud editor, so it's enough to load `ace.js` from somewhere and it will try to load `mode-javascript.js` from the same source. I do not know if this will work in your case with the combined 3 scripts (I don't have enough JS knowledge). But anyway you also need `mode-javascript.js` file for using "JS mode".

> I've tried adjusting my CSP script-src to the following
> ...
> `script-src 'self' blob: chrome-extension:;`
> ...
> The only CSP that actually worked so far was copy-pasting the entire chrome extension url
> `chrome-extension://<extuuid>/js/worker-javascript.js`

it breaks my harmonious picture of the universe. In CSP, the network scheme-source (eg `http:`) always covers any source host used with the same scheme (eg `http://example.com/path/file_name`). And non-network schemes (eg `data:`) cannot be used with `host_name/path/file_name`.
So using `chrome-extension:` should be totally enough to allow any `chrome-extension://<extuuid>/path/filename.js`. Щf course, vendor schemes introduce some specifics, but not so much!
Could you confirm that you have not messed up the results of the checks, and `chrome-extension:` is not enough for permission, and you need to specify the full path?

> 

I think that [Content Security Policy for Ace editor](https://csplite.com/csp/test306/) with enabled Worker adapted for your particular case should be:

```
child-src 'self' blob: chrome-extension:;
img-src data:;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' chrome-extension:;
style-src 'unsafe-inline';
worker-src 'self' blob: chrome-extension:;
```

Note that `'unsafe-eval'` is required if `worker-javascript.js` is used.
Alternatively you can disable Worker by setting `useWorker: false` or `editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false)`. With worker disabled the CSP should be just:

```
img-src data:;
script-src 'self';
style-src 'unsafe-inline';
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be work.

```
import ace from 'ace-builds';
ace.config.set("loadWorkerFromBlob", false)
```